# How can I differentiate a function with the form of $y^x$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

The title says it all.
So if $f(x,y)=y^x$ what is $f`(x,y)$

Comment: If $g(x) = a^x$, then $g'(x) = a^x\ln a$. I assume you mean the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\frac{d}{dx}[y^x] = \frac{d}{dx}[e^{x\ln(y)}] = e^{x\ln y} \frac{d}{dx}[x\ln y] = e^{x\ln y} \frac{d}{dx}[x]\times \ln y = \ln y \times e^{x\ln y} = y^x \ln y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$a^x=e^{\ln(a)x}.$$ Now just apply the chain rule and remember that $\ln a$ is just a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick which is very useful and makes life easier when you face produstcs, quotients, powers is logarithmic differentiation.

Consider $$z=y^x\implies \log(z)=x \log(y)$$ Differentiate $$\frac{z'}z=\log(y)\implies z'=z \log(y)=y^x \log(y)$$

If $y$ was also a function of $x$, it would have been $$\frac{z'}z=\log(y)+x \frac{y'}y\implies z'=y^x\left(\log(y)+x \frac{y'}y \right) $$